# Margin 0 auto don't work in my case

Tags: html, css, margin

Here is part of my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZNJG/3/)

I've tried to find a solution to center the `.person` div's inside of the `.team` div.

I spent about an hour to figure out what I'm doing wrong without any success.

Is it possible to make the `.person` divs remain centered even when the width of the page is changed? In my case I have a static `width: 768px`, but even still, I can't center the div's.

Comment: You've only applied `margin: 0 auto` to the `.team` so only this element will be centered in its parent.  What's the `width` of its parent element?  If you want it centered on the viewport, then the parent's `width` must be 100% of the viewport.

Comment: @Sparky Parent of `.team` element is `.content`. `.content` have `width: 744px;`. You can add css for content class in jsFiddle example.

Comment: How can `.team` be wider than its parent?  How are you going to center something in a place where it has no space on either side?  If you want it centered in the viewport, then the parent must be as wide as the viewport (100%) and then `margin: 0 auto` will work.

Comment: See this demo, where `#child` is centered in `#parent`:  http://jsfiddle.net/k8LFn/

Comment: Same demo, but `#parent` is not wide enough to contain `#child`:  http://jsfiddle.net/k8LFn/1/

Comment: Ok I understand. but I want center 1st and 2nd row with `.person` in `.team` container.

Comment: If you want to center `.person`, then you need to apply `margin: 0 auto` to `.person` and **not** its parent element, `.team`.

Comment: It can't work, there is `float: left;`

Comment: Correct. You can't do both... so why did you think it should work by applying `margin: 0 auto` to its parent?

Comment: Look on @lukeocom answer. This is what I want.

Comment: Yes, that's fine but he's not using `float`.  My point is that there's nothing wrong with `margin: 0 auto` if you know how & when to apply it properly.

Comment: Yes, yes. It was my mistake to try using this instead find good solution but actually on clock I see 4am so I should go sleep :). Anyway thanks for help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the person class to `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`.
You can then apply `text-align:center` to the team class.
This should achieve the desired result.

```
.team {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.person {
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:left;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;

    &:nth-child(5n+1) {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
```

I changed the border colour for testing purposes only.

fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sZNJG/7/

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. I will accept your answer if all will be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `text-align: center;` the `team` class. See [jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/GA66d/1/).

Comment: It center `.person` div's inside `.team` div.